# Is Mono a good alternative for mobile developers that want to use .NET?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile

How robust is it? Has anyone had any experience with it? Please list any good or bad experience you have had. It would be very useful to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IPhone/IPad development you will need a Mac regardless you are using mono or not.

I am .Net developer and I found it was a short curve developing for Cocoa and Android.

I'm sure mono does its work, but I don't like the idea of adding a new layer on my development learning process just because I am more used to one specific language.

Getting used to Android having a .net background goes really smooth if you used to C#.

Eclipse IDE using java fairly close to Visual Studio and .net. Just try to get a real Android device for debugging once the Android Simulator that comes with the SDK is unbelievable slow regardless you are using Windows, OSX, Linux based OS

IOS development was more painful mainly because we are, from .net, very spoiled from the rich Visual Studio comparing to XCode from Apple.

Objective-c can be very hard to figure sometimes for C#/VB.net developers, but I do believe searching among the thousands of answered questions from Stackoverflow will help you out, punctually speaking, the same way it did for me.